# continuity of $f(x)=\frac{xy_0}{x^2+y_0^2}$ at $x_0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, epsilon-delta

I'm trying to prove $f(x)=\frac{xy_0}{x^2+y_0^2}$($y_0\neq0)$ is continuous at $x_0$  using $\epsilon-\delta$ definition. I tried

$$
\left|\frac{xy_0}{x^2+y_0^2}-\frac{x_0y_0}{x_0^2+y_0^2}\right|
= |y_0|\left|\frac{x}{x^2+y_0^2}-\frac{x_0}{x_0^2+y_0^2}\right| =|y_0|\left|\frac{x(x_0^2+y_0^2)-x_0(x^2+y_0^2)}{(x^2+y_0^2)(x_0^2+y_0^2)}\right|
\leq|y_0|\left|\frac{x(x_0^2+y_0^2)-x_0(x^2+y_0^2)}{x^2(x_0^2+y_0^2)}\right|
=\left|\frac{y_0}{x_0^2+y_0^2}\right|\left|\frac{x(x_0^2+y_0^2)-x_0(x^2+y_0^2)}{x^2}\right|
$$

and I don't see how to proceed from here.

Comment: Why would you exclude $y_0 = 0$? The function would just be the identically zero function.

Comment: @giobrach except at $x=0$, in which case asking for continuity there would not make sense.

Comment: Exactly, you'd have to exclude that from the domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at:
$|y_0||\frac{x(x_0^2+y_0^2)-x_0(x^2+y_0^2)}{(x^2+y_0^2)(x_0^2+y_0^2)}|$

I would add and subtract the same term, that factors with the terms already there.

$|y_0||\frac{x(x_0^2+y_0^2)-x_0(x_0^2+y_0^2)+x_0(x_0^2+y_0^2)-x_0(x^2+y_0^2)}{(x^2+y_0^2)(x_0^2+y_0^2)}|\\
|y_0||\frac{(x-x_0)(x_0^2+y_0^2)+x_0(x_0^2-x^2)}{(x^2+y_0^2)(x_0^2+y_0^2)}|\\
|x-x_0||\frac{y_0(x_0^2+y_0^2)+x_0y_0(x_0+x)}{(x^2+y_0^2)(x_0^2+y_0^2)}|\\
$

And then show that the factor on the right is bounded.

More abstractly:

if $g(a) \ne 0$ and $f(x),g(x)$ are continuous at $a.$

Then:

$\lim_\limits{x\to a} \frac {f(x)}{g(x)} = \frac {f(a)}{g(a)}$

Comment: Thanks this approach is what I wanted

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend that instead of 
$$|y_0|\left|\frac{x(x_0^2+y_0^2)-x_0(x^2+y_0^2)}{(x^2+y_0^2)(x_0^2+y_0^2)}\right|\leq|y_0|\left|\frac{x(x_0^2+y_0^2)-x_0(x^2+y_0^2)}{x^2(x_0^2+y_0^2)}\right|$$
you use
$$|y_0|\left|\frac{x(x_0^2+y_0^2)-x_0(x^2+y_0^2)}{(x^2+y_0^2)(x_0^2+y_0^2)}\right|\leq\frac{1}{|y_0|\cdot(x_0^2+y_0^2)}\left|x(x_0^2+y_0^2)-x_0(x^2+y_0^2)\right|$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer